# Client Javascript getting data from backend express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have built an Express Server like this:

```
var mysql = require('mysql2');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
var PORT = 3000;

app.get('/getDataFromDatabase', function(req, res) {
  console.log("Called")


  var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "", // Password is filled ()
    database: "casesdb"
  });

  con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    con.query("SELECT * FROM cases", function (err, result, fields) {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.status(200).send(result);
      console.log("Test")
    });
  });
});

app.listen(PORT, () =>
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${PORT}!`),
);
```

My Goal is to call the /getDataFromDatabase in client javascript and then use that data. How would I go about that?

Comment: Is this code not working?

Comment: The code is working, I just can't figure out how to call that from clientside Javascript.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following on client-side:

```html
<script>

 fetch('http://localhost:3000/getDataFromDatabase')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));

</script>
```